# Is there any tool to change spir-v shader, so I can insert and delete some instructions

Tags: graphics, nvidia, vulkan, amd-gpu

I want to edit spv directly. Is there any tool to change spir-v shader, so I can insert and delete some instructions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SPIRV-Cross](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/SPIRV-Cross) will let you cross compile SPIR-V to GLSL and a variety of other shading languages and then you can edit and recompile the shaders.